# Passing a 2 dimensional array to a function using a pointer in C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to pass this array to the function but i keep on getting, 
 **error C2664: 'correctans' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::string [3][3]' to 'std::string **'** , don;t mind the silly questions in the code its just random for testing.

code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

int correctans(string *arr1, string **arr2, int *arr3, int questions, int choices)
{
int count=0;
int ans;

    for(int i=0; i<questions; i++)
    {
        cout << "Question #" << i+1;
      cout << arr1[i] << endl;
      for(int j=0; j<choices; j++)
          cout << j+1 << arr2[i][j] << " ";
      cout << "your answer:";
      cin >> ans;
      if(ans==arr3[i])
          count++;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int correct;
    string Questions[3]={"HowAreYou", "HowManyHandsDoYouHave", "AreYouCrazyOrCrazy"};
    string Choices[3][3]={{"Banana", "Peanut", "Fine"},{"Five", "Two", "One"},{"I'mCrazy", "I'mCrazyBanana", "I'mDoubleCrazy"}};
    int Answers[3]={3, 2, 3};

    correct=correctans(Questions, Choices, Answers, 3, 3);
    cout << "You have " << correct << " correct answers" <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

int correctans(string *arr1, string (&arr2)[3][3], int *arr3, int questions, int choices)`

Comment: but I have a question what if i didn't know what is the size of the 2d array what can i use instead of  [3][3]  cause i tried changing the number just from the function but it didn't work i want to be able to set it up to any size is that possible?

Comment: @WildBegginner: you could make ``correctans`` template function. ``template<typename T, int SIZE> correctans( ..., string(&arr)[SIZE][SIZE], ... )``. But if you don't know the size at the compile time, then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Passing multidimensional arrays can get very confusing. I recommend creating a singlepointer to the start of your array, and passing that pointer:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

int correctans(string *arr1, string *arr2, int *arr3, int questions, int choices)
{
int count=0;
int ans;

    for(int i=0; i<questions; i++)
    {
        cout << "Question #" << i+1;
      cout << arr1[i] << endl;
      for(int j=0; j<choices; j++)
          cout << j+1 << arr2[i][j] << " ";
      cout << "your answer:";
      cin >> ans;
      if(ans==arr3[i])
          count++;
    }

    return count;
}

int main()
{
    int correct;
    string Questions[3]={"HowAreYou", "HowManyHandsDoYouHave", "AreYouCrazyOrCrazy"};
    string Choices[3][3]={{"Banana", "Peanut", "Fine"},{"Five", "Two", "One"},{"I'mCrazy", "I'mCrazyBanana", "I'mDoubleCrazy"}};
    int Answers[3]={3, 2, 3};

    string* choicesPtr=&Choices[0][0];
    correct=correctans(Questions, choicesPtr, Answers, 3, 3);
    cout << "You have " << correct << " correct answers" <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiles and executes.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you can use something like 'string [][] & rArray'
(or exactly: string [3][3] & rArray), of course you should pass the actual dimensions as parameters as well.

The compiler accepted this:
    string  arr2[3][3]
as parameter. But i would try to improve passing a pointer instead of copying an array by value. Since you are using stl::string you could also try vector< vector< string > >.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as compiler said `std::string [3][3]` can not be converted to `std::string **`.

You can try this

```
int correctans(string *arr1, string (* arr2)[ 3 ], int *arr3, int questions, int choices)
```

or this

```
int correctans(string *arr1, string arr2[][ 3 ], int *arr3, int questions, int choices)
```

But better solution is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: the second one worked but it is not passed using a pointer. thanks though @kotlomoy

Comment: @WildBegginner Actually `string arr2[][3]` implicitly converted to `string (* arr2)[3]`. So both are identical for compiler. BTW the first one works now (I missed parentheses in first edition of my post)